# Typescript async and this scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular-material

I've set up a simple service to pull data from a db, the service works fine but when I try to take the data from the service and into a component via an aysnc function, I can't seem to pass the scope of the function through using "this".

Any ideas? I must be doing something obviously wrong as I'm new to development.

Here's the service code which works fine;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VenueserviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  httpGetFeatures() {
    console.log("inFeatures")
    this.http.post("http://******************",
  {
         "command": "get_feature",
         "classes":"F,G"
  })

  .subscribe(
         (val) => {
        console.log("inSubscribe")
        console.log(val)
          return(val)
          //this.parseFeatures(val)
         },
         response => {
         console.log("POST call in error", response);
         },
                 () => {
  });
  }



  parseFeatures (val: any) {
    console.log("in parse Features")
    console.log(val)
  }



}
```

and here is the component TS, the problem is "this" throws an error because  it's undefined as I believe the scope of this isn't being passed through. Its the final async function at the bottom.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from "./testfile.json";
import * as catdata from "../categories/cattestfile.json";
import {VenueserviceService} from "../../services/venueservice.service"


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private venueService: VenueserviceService) { }

  panelOpenState = false;
  title = 'Cotswolds Destinations';

  venues: any = (data as any).default;

  categories: any = (catdata as any).default;

  formatLabel(value: number) {
    if (value >= 1000) {
      return Math.round(value / 1000) + 'm';
    }

    return value;
  }

  value = 'Clear me!';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Homepage Start");
    console.log(this.categories);
    console.log(this.venues);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.venues.name);
    for(var i=0; i < this.venues.length; i++){
    console.log(this.venues[i]);
    }
    console.log("Homepage End");
    let categories = this.venueService.httpGetFeatures()

    console.log(categories)

  }
}



const getData =  async () => {
  const data  = await this.venueService.httpGetFeatures()
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Just an FIY, do not post the actual link to your API endpoint :-)

Comment: @monstertjie_za i won't next time thanks :/ for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest is you do this

**Service File**

```
    httpGetFeatures() {
        console.log("inFeatures")
        return this.http.post("http://cotswoldsdestinations.co.uk:8443",
        {
            "command": "get_feature",
            "classes":"F,G"
        })
    }
```

**Component File**

```
fetchedData:any;
const getData =  async () => {
  this.venueService.httpGetFeatures()
    .subscribe( data => { this.fetchedData = data });
}
```

Comment: That is a great suggestion but it still didn't work, "any" throws an error because it's being used as a value rather than a type. "data" errors because it has an "any" type. And 'this' still isn't passed through, it's erroring because it's an undefined object. Banging head against wall lol

Comment: Can u paste the actual stack trace? what exactly do you mean by this isn't passed. "this" is a keyword. you cant pass keywords in functions. You can just edit the question and paste the actual stack trace of the error so that people can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

1st, you haven't returned anything in VenueserviceService.httpGetFeatures, it's return type is void.

2nd, you are expecting a promise in your getData lambda function, as you are using asyc-await syntax. Either do this:

```
httpGetFeatures() {
  return this.http.post("http://cotswoldsdestinations.co.uk:8443",
  {
    "command": "get_feature",
    "classes":"F,G"
  }).toPromise();
}
```

Or just subscribe to returned observable without awaiting:

```
httpGetFeatures() {
  return this.http.post("http://cotswoldsdestinations.co.uk:8443",
  {
    "command": "get_feature",
    "classes":"F,G"
  });
}
const getData = () => {
  this.venueService.httpGetFeatures().subscribe(data =>
    console.log(data);
  );
}
```

This is all ok if you defined `getData` within some component that has `venueService: VenueserviceService` passed via DI in it's constructor.

For it to work properly, define getData as a member of Home page component's class, e.g.:

```
export component HomePageComponent {
  constructor(private venueService: VenueserviceService) {}

  getData() {
    this.venueService.httpGetFeatures().subscribe(data =>
      console.log(data);
    );
  }
}
```